# Is it possible to export 'PRINT' commands into a file via bcp?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I want to export a result of a PRINT command. I don't want to use the normal SQL Server logs. Is that possible with bcp? Because the following command does not work.

Example:

```
SET @IPE = 'bcp PRINT ''Test''  queryout ' + @Path + '1b_Log_change_log_entry.txt -c -T'
```

Result:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]BCP host-files must contain at least one column
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations
NULL
BCP copy out failed
NULL
```

Comment: `Print` is not a query but `Select` is..  Try Select instead of Print.. `'bcp Select ''Test''  queryout..`

Comment: Thank you! Good comment! Please formulate that as an answer. Only that's way how I can mark this question as complete.

Comment: Added it as answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Print` is not a query but `Select` is.. Try `Select` instead of `Print`

```
SET @IPE = 'bcp SELECT ''Test''  queryout ' + @Path + '1b_Log_change_log_entry.txt -c -T'
```